# JSON Serialization Issue: InvalidDefinitionException:

Tags: java, json, jackson, rest-assured

I have a scenario, where I need to perform a negative test scenario.

This a PUT call to update customer object.

I need to convert the object into JSON and them remove a mandatory attribute before applying to the payload.

Now when I shall supply a payload with a missing attribute, I am expecting 400 response and error message.

I have used the following code but having InvalidDefinitionException

**Error**

```
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

**Code:**

```
  UpdateCustomerModel updateCustomerModel = new UpdateCustomerModel()
    updateCustomerModel.setFirstName("abc");
    updateCustomerModel.setLastName("abc");
    updateCustomerModel.setEmail("a@a.com");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(updateCustomerModel);

    JSONObject updateCustomerJson = new JSONObject(json);

    updateCustomerJson.getJSONObject("customer").remove("email");

    Response response =
     given().filter(new RequestLoggingFilter(this.requestCapture))

     .header("Authorization", getSession().getToken()).body(updateCustomerJson)
     .body(updateCustomerJson)
     .when()
     .put(Resource.updateCustomer)
     .then()
     .extract().response();
```

**PAYLOAD:**
    Mandatory attributes in payload are;

```
firstname, lastname and email

{
    "customer": {
        "id": null,
        "firstname": "Chuck",
        "lastname": "Patterson",
        "store_id": null,
        "website_id": 1,
        "addresses": [

        ],
        "default_billing": null,
        "default_shipping": null
    }
}
```

Tried R&D many configs but no joy

e.g

mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);

Can someone please point out any direction?

Comment: Do you need multiple calls to .body(updateCustomerJson)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson seems to be unable to serialize the `JSONObject` you're attempting to pass in as the body. Why don't you try to convert it back to String after removing the unwanted fields?

Comment: Brilliant Suggestion Aris!

I just added .toString() as following and it resolved the issue for now.
 .body(updateCustomerJson.toString())

However, it's still the mystery why JSONObject was not able to covert it.

Many thanks for your support Aris